PDF download on WooCommerce order is complete
I'm trying to download/export a PDF that a customer selects with a product. The customer selected a document id, I fetched that document from Elasticsearch and created a pdf for that document. Now I want it to force download this pdf once the order status is complete, but no pdf is being exported. How do I make it work?
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'check_order_for_product');

function check_order_for_product($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $official_id = $order->get_meta('official_id');
    $generate_pdf_flag = $order->get_meta('generate_pdf') === '1' ? true : false;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->get_product_id() == 1195) {
            generate_es_report_as_pdf($official_id, $generate_pdf_flag);
        }
    }
}

The generate report function:
function generate_es_report_as_pdf($official_id, $generate_pdf_flag) {
    ...
    ...
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    $filename = $official_id . '.pdf';
    // Send the PDF to the browser for download
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    $mpdf->Output('php://output', 'D');
}

Am I missing out on something?
I've also tried the basic export with $mpdf->Output('php://output', 'D'); but that seems to not have worked as well.
Note: I don't want the files to be stored on the server as I have to implement an additional security mechanism and that could be part of the second version.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
